# Javascript: decodeURIComponent refuses to work

Tags: javascript, urldecode

I got this guy. He decode a string into a readble one.

```
decodeURIComponent("Invalid Ticker Name \u0027t\u0027 at line: 3")
"Invalid Ticker Name 't' at line: 3"
```

Now look at this one. It tells us that the source of this string (array item) is really a string.

```
typeof decodeURIComponent(errorsArr[i])
"string"
```

But when I try to decode the array item, it just doesn't work.

```
decodeURIComponent(errorsArr[i])
"Invalid Ticker Name \u0027t\u0027 at line: 3"
```

What to do?

Comment: Looks like its working to me... at least, working like it's written to work.  Can you post what you expect from it?

Comment: The last one only says decodeURI not decodeURIComponent

Comment: Thank you. it is a typo, but did not solved my problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem been solved.

As been written in the code

```
// If the document was sent as 'application/javascript' or
// 'text/javascript', then the browser wraps the text in a <pre>
// tag and performs html encoding on the contents.  In this case,
// we need to pull the original text content from the text node's
// nodeValue property to retrieve the unmangled content.
// Note that IE6 only understands text/html
```

I have started serving the file as html/text, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know what it is.  Your string has a literal `\u0027` in it.  You can verify this behavior in a browser with:

```
javascript:alert("\u0027");alert("\\u0027");
```

When you enter it as:

```
Invalid Ticker Name \u0027t\u0027 at line: 3
```

It's substituting out the unicode character.  Why can't you use `%27`?

Comment: Its comming from the browser, as the callback of a json call. I cannot control it, but I can change the string before decoding it. Thank you! I'll guve it a try.

Comment: Are you actually using a json parser?  they should substitute such sequences out for you.

Comment: the content type i send is pplication/json. The plugin developer "https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload" said this:  If the document was sent as 'application/javascript' or 'text/javascript', then the browser wraps the text in a <pre> tag and performs html encoding on the contents. But I send correct. I must find where's the problem. Thank you @Wug, you showed me the direction.